# Reach-router in react won't re-render with urlParams on the same path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url-parameters, reach-router

I'm creating a single page application on an internal UI. A menu appears on the left of the screen (`CollectionsInventory`), which contains `Link`s generated from an API call, and on the right, the resulting object (a `Collection`) is shown in his component. The prop is passed through a `url-parameters`. I'm also using a `Grid` component from patternfly4 to manage the UI. This is what it looks like:

```js
<Grid hasGutter>
  <GridItem span={3}>
    {data != null ?
      <CollectionsInventory collections={data[0].collections}/>
    :
      <React.Fragment>
        <Spinner />
      </React.Fragment>
    }
  </GridItem>
  <GridItem span={9}>
    <Router primary={false}>
      <React.Fragment path="/" />
      <Collection path="collection/:collectionName" />
    </Router>
  </GridItem>
</Grid>
```

Here's the problem; I can make a collection appear by clicking on the corresponding link, or accessing it directly (useful if, say, a user wants to access a bookmark he has of his favorite collection).  But then, **the collection is stuck there. Whenever I click on a new link, nothing changes**. Maybe because  it's on the same path? Is there a way to make a link trigger a re-render? Or am I not using the correct components since the menu with the links is outside the router?

In `CollectionsInventory`, the links are shown in a table, and are generated from a collection name like so:

```
const defaultRows = collectionList.map( collection => {
  const collectionLink=`collection/${encodeURI(collection.name)}`

  return {
    cells: [
      {
        title:
          <Link to={collectionLink}>
            {collection.name}
          </Link>,
        name: collection.name
      },
      collection.resourceType,
      collection.size
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my `Collection` component didn't re-render when the `collectionName` prop was updated. I tough the react component would re-render whenever we changed the props, but that apparently wasn't the case. So I added an effect with `props.collectionName` to relaunch the apiFetch process whenever it changes, and Voila! The `Collection` component updates whenever I select a new link.

Bonus: To be exact, the fetchApi method I'm using is a callback, which gets modified everytime `props.collectionName` is modified. Here's the shorten version:

```js
const Collection = ({ collectionName }) => {
  const fetchData = useCallback(()=>{
    const apiPath = `/collection/${collectionName}`;
    /* do stuff to retrieve the data and set it in the state, or handle errors*/
  },[collectionName]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  },[fetchData]);

  return(
   /*The actual content*/
  );
};
```